# Backbone error when creating a second (collection) view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, yeoman

I'm trying to create a second view for my collection.

main.js

```
window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Routers: {},
    init: function () {
        console.log('Hello from Backbone!');
        var book = new this.Models.BookModel({
            title: 'JS is awesome',
            author: 'Douglas Crackford'
        });

        var book2 = new this.Models.BookModel({
            title: 'JS the good parts',
            author: 'Douglas Crackford'
        });

        var bookCollection = new this.Collections.BookCollection;
        bookCollection.add([book, book2]);


        var view = new this.Views.BookView();
        //next line creates error 
        var peopleView = new this.Views.PeopleView();
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    App.init();
});
```

BookView.js

```
App.Views = App.Views || {};

(function () {
    App.Views.BookView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $('#footer'),

        template: _.template($ ('#books').html()),

        initialize: function () {
            console.log('BookView initialized');
        },

        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        }

    });
})();
```

PeopleView.js

```
App.Views = App.Views || {};

(function () {
    App.Views.PeopleView = Backbone.View.extend({

       tagName: 'ul',

       initialize: function() {
           console.log('peopleView init')
       }

    });
})();
```

Output created

```
Hello from Backbone!                                main.js:8
BookView initialized                                BookView.js:11
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function     main.js:24
```

I find this error strange. If I copy the code from BookView to PeopleView and only call this new PeopleView (and edit out BookView) I get the same error, while the code looks valid because it executed (see the console.log). 
 I find this very strange. What part am I missing?

edit:

Added picture to show the execution order.

[image]

Comment: Try remove App.Views = App.Views || {}; which is not executed at the same time than what is beetwen (function(){...})(), + it's not usefull since your App.js is already initialized with App.Views = {}

Comment: Unfortunately no effect when I remove  App.Views = App.Views || {};

Comment: You sure you have all js files included in the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is one of scope.

When the init method is called, it is called in the Window scope, as such the value of `this` is `Window`. You can `console.log(this)` in your init method to see.

Couple of things you can do. As you attached `App` to the `window` object, you can call it directly:

```
  var bookCollection = new App.Collections.BookCollection;
```

Or you can bind the call of init to the App object:

```
App.init.call(App);
```

This will bind the value of `this` to the first argument of `call`.

You can simplify this further by binding directly when you pass the function doc ready method:

```
$(document).ready(App.init.bind(App));
```

[More Info On Scopes](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/)

Comment: I've tinkered with requireJS and encountered some problems with templates, will look into it again. I also added a picture of the execution order. This is a basic yeoman set-up btw.

Comment: Made a significant change to my answer.

Comment: No worries. I do urge you to read more about scopes and closures and to become familiar with an AMD system like requirejs

Comment: I'm currently rewriting everything in requireJS and i got it working. What i really like in using requireJS is that you have to stop and think which file you have to include in the define part. This will force you to think about every part of your application.